# Maven: How show the @DisplayName?

Tags: maven, junit, maven-3, junit5, maven-surefire-plugin

Using `JUnit 5`, about `@DisplayName`, through either Eclipse or STS4 appears the respective description, it does not matter if the `@Test` method passes or fails. Until here all work as expected.

Through Maven how could be possible show the *display name* too? Currently does not show nothing and test passes/fails as expected, about the `surefire-plugin` it is declared as:

```
      <plugin>
          <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
          <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
          <version>2.22.2</version>
      </plugin>
```

The purpose is enhanced the report. Through either the `terminal` or `CI`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html#surefire-extensions-and-reports-configuration-for-displayname), you need to configure the plugin as shown below. However, this requires surefire plugin version `3.0.0-M4` or greater, so you will need to upgrade from `2.22.2` to use it.

```xml
<build>
    <plugins>
        ...
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <statelessTestsetReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5Xml30StatelessReporter">
                    <disable>false</disable>
                    <version>3.0</version>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                    <usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>true</usePhrasedTestSuiteClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseClassName>
                    <usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>true</usePhrasedTestCaseMethodName>
                </statelessTestsetReporter>
                <consoleOutputReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5ConsoleOutputReporter">
                    <disable>false</disable>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                </consoleOutputReporter>
                <statelessTestsetInfoReporter implementation="org.apache.maven.plugin.surefire.extensions.junit5.JUnit5StatelessTestsetInfoReporter">
                    <disable>false</disable>
                    <usePhrasedFileName>false</usePhrasedFileName>
                    <usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>true</usePhrasedClassNameInRunning>
                    <usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>true</usePhrasedClassNameInTestCaseSummary>
                </statelessTestsetInfoReporter>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```